# Windows 2012 R2 Server Manager Fails to Load

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, eventviewer, windows

I am unable to open Server Manager on our Windows 2012-R2 system.  The error states:

```
Server Manager cannot run because of an error in a user settings file. Click OK to restore default settings.......
```

Clicking `OK` does not fix the issue.  I've run .Net verification and repair tools and the problems still persists.  I am unable to use Event Viewer because it crashes with the error:

`MMC has detected and error in a snap-in and will unload it.`

I have searched online with no luck on how to resolve this further. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your OS 64-bit ?

If so, this it's the same problem as in 2008 R2.

Get this patch: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688730 (ignore any install warnings).
And then install latest .net frameworks.

If the system does not allow you to install the patch above (in some cases it says it's already applied), just uninstall all .net versions and then install the latest available for 2012 R2.

After that, open Server Manager, right click Features and select Add Features.

Expand .Net Framework [latest version] Features, select the check box next to the .NET Framework [latest version] click on Install.